# How to save entries sorted by entrytype in JabRef?

Tags: jabref

With JabRef it is possible to specify the sort order used when saving and exporting a bib file. When exporting the bib file, you can specify to use the current sorting of the entries shown in the GUI. When setting the library properties, there is no corresponding option in the *save sort order* section. I want to sort the bib file so that entries are grouped with a primary sort criterion of *entrytype*, but this is not in the drop down list. Is it possible to save a bib file sorted based on entrytype directly from JabRef?

Answer (score 3):

Why bother about? Like in any database, when each entry have enough information, the order in which each entry is stored is completely irrelevant. However, if you insist, for example, to order by the keys in inverse order:

<kbd>File</kbd>
   <kbd>Library Properties</kbd>
      **Save sort order**
           🔘 Save entries ordered as specified 
               Primary sort criterion `bibtextekey`▼ ☑    Descending 
      <kbd>OK</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>